# Custom align environment which auto breaks line before = and aligns at =

Tags: math-mode, automation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
   \lcm(13, 7) &= (13 \cdot 7):\gcd(13, 7) \\
               &= (13 \cdot 7):1 \\
               &= \overset{10+3}{13} \cdot 7 \\
               &= 10 \cdot 7+3 \cdot 7 \\
               &= 70+21 \\
               &= \boxed{91}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it possibile to define a custom environment, say `customalign`, which let obtain the same output by writing the equation on a single line like this?

```
\begin{customalign}
   \lcm(13, 7) = (13 \cdot 7):\gcd(13, 7) = (13 \cdot 7):1 = \overset{10+3}{13} \cdot 7 = 10 \cdot 7+3 \cdot 7 = 70+21 = \boxed{91}
\end{customalign}
```

The `customalign` environment should automatically:

- breaks line before every `=` sign starting from the second one, ie it should auto adds `\\` before every `=` sign starting from the second one;
- aligns at every `=` sign, ie it should auto adds `&` before every `=` sign but after the `\\`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `customalign` is defined using [`newenviron`](//ctan.org/pkg/newenviron) in order to tap into the `\BODY` of the environment. Every `=` is replaced by `\\ &=` via `\xpatchcmd*`. A second `\xpatchcmd` then restores the first global replacement back to only `&=`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,regexpatch,environ}
\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}

\NewEnviron{customalign}{%
  \xpatchcmd*{\BODY}{=}{\\ &=}{}{}% Global replacement "=" > "\\ &="
  \xpatchcmd{\BODY}{\\ &=}{&=}{}{}% First replacement "\\ &=" > "&="
  \begin{align*}
    \BODY% Set align with replacement
  \end{align*}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \lcm(13, 7) &= (13 \cdot 7) : \gcd(13, 7) \\
              &= (13 \cdot 7) : 1 \\
              &= \overset{10 + 3}{13} \cdot 7 \\
              &= 10 \cdot 7 + 3 \cdot 7 \\
              &= 70 + 21 \\
              &= \boxed{91}
\end{align*}

\begin{customalign}
   \lcm(13, 7) = (13 \cdot 7) : \gcd(13, 7) 
               = (13 \cdot 7) : 1 
               = \overset{10 + 3}{13} \cdot 7 
               = 10 \cdot 7 + 3 \cdot 7 
               = 70 + 21 
               = \boxed{91}
\end{customalign}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I get this warning though `Package l3regex Warning: This package is obsolete --- use 'expl3'`, is something to be worried of?

Comment: @soundwave: I have an up-to-date version of TeX Live ([here](https://pastebin.com/raw/Yb5qATgt) is my file list; obtained by adding `\listfiles` to your preamble and examining the `.log`). Update all your packages and try again, maybe?

Comment: I think it is a problem with overleaf, not a big deal I guess, thanks!

Comment: I appreciate both answers, but accepted this since it's the only one working in quicklatex.

Comment: @Werner you and `egreg` introduced auto breaking to the the next generation level...Thank you both...

Answer (score 7):

This implementation avoids cumbersome replacements:

1. the body of the environment is split at `=`;
2. the first item is set apart and passed to `split` followed by `&=`;
3. the remaining item are delivered, separated by `\\ &=`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{breakalign}{b}
 {
  \begin{equation}
  \soundwave_breakalign:nnn { #1 } { split } { }
  \end{equation}
 }
 {}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{breakalign*}{b}
 {
  \begin{equation*}
  \soundwave_breakalign:nnn { #1 } { split } { }
  \end{equation*}
 }
 {}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{breakaligned}{O{c} b}
 {
  \soundwave_breakalign:nnn { #2 } { aligned } { #1 }
 }
 {}

\tl_new:N \l__soundwave_breakalign_left_tl
\seq_new:N \l__soundwave_breakalign_body_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \soundwave_breakalign:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__soundwave_breakalign_body_seq { = } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__soundwave_breakalign_body_seq \l__soundwave_breakalign_left_tl
  \tl_if_empty:nTF { #3 } { \begin{#2} } { \begin{#2}[#3] }
  \l__soundwave_breakalign_left_tl &=
  \seq_use:Nn \l__soundwave_breakalign_body_seq { \\ &= }
  \end{#2}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{breakalign*}
   \lcm(13, 7) = (13 \cdot 7):\gcd(13, 7)
               = (13 \cdot 7):1
               = \overset{10+3}{13} \cdot 7
               = 10 \cdot 7+3 \cdot 7
               = 70+21
               = \boxed{91}
\end{breakalign*}

\begin{breakalign}
   \lcm(13, 7) = (13 \cdot 7):\gcd(13, 7)
               = (13 \cdot 7):1
               = \overset{10+3}{13} \cdot 7
               = 10 \cdot 7+3 \cdot 7
               = 70+21
               = \boxed{91}
\end{breakalign}

\begin{align*}
&\begin{breakaligned}
   \lcm(13, 7) = (13 \cdot 7):\gcd(13, 7)
               = (13 \cdot 7):1
               = \overset{10+3}{13} \cdot 7
               = 10 \cdot 7+3 \cdot 7
               = 70+21
               = \boxed{91}
\end{breakaligned}
&&
\begin{breakaligned}
   \lcm(13, 7) = (13 \cdot 7):\gcd(13, 7)
               = (13 \cdot 7):1
               = \overset{10+3}{13} \cdot 7
               = 10 \cdot 7+3 \cdot 7
               = 70+21
               = \boxed{91}
\end{breakaligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

There are three environments:

1. `breakalign` will get a number;
2. `breakalign*` will be unnumbered;
3. `breakaligned` can be used as a subsidiary environment and accepts the usual `[t]` or `[b]` options like `aligned` for vertical alignment.

[image]

A version compatible with older (but not too old) versions of TeX Live.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{environ}

\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewEnviron{breakalign}
 {
  \begin{equation}
  \soundwave_breakalign:Vnn \BODY { split } { }
  \end{equation}
 }

\NewEnviron{breakalign*}
 {
  \begin{equation*}
  \soundwave_breakalign:Vnn \BODY { split } { }
  \end{equation*}
 }

\NewEnviron{breakaligned}[1][c]
 {
  \soundwave_breakalign:Vnn \BODY { aligned } { #1 }
 }


\tl_new:N \l__soundwave_breakalign_left_tl
\seq_new:N \l__soundwave_breakalign_body_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \soundwave_breakalign:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__soundwave_breakalign_body_seq { = } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__soundwave_breakalign_body_seq \l__soundwave_breakalign_left_tl
  \tl_if_empty:nTF { #3 } { \begin{#2} } { \begin{#2}[#3] }
  \l__soundwave_breakalign_left_tl &=
  \seq_use:Nn \l__soundwave_breakalign_body_seq { \\ &= }
  \end{#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \soundwave_breakalign:nnn { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{breakalign*}
   \lcm(13, 7) = (13 \cdot 7):\gcd(13, 7)
               = (13 \cdot 7):1
               = \overset{10+3}{13} \cdot 7
               = 10 \cdot 7+3 \cdot 7
               = 70+21
               = \boxed{91}
\end{breakalign*}

\begin{breakalign}
   \lcm(13, 7) = (13 \cdot 7):\gcd(13, 7)
               = (13 \cdot 7):1
               = \overset{10+3}{13} \cdot 7
               = 10 \cdot 7+3 \cdot 7
               = 70+21
               = \boxed{91}
\end{breakalign}

\begin{align*}
&\begin{breakaligned}
   \lcm(13, 7) = (13 \cdot 7):\gcd(13, 7)
               = (13 \cdot 7):1
               = \overset{10+3}{13} \cdot 7
               = 10 \cdot 7+3 \cdot 7
               = 70+21
               = \boxed{91}
\end{breakaligned}
&&
\begin{breakaligned}
   \lcm(13, 7) = (13 \cdot 7):\gcd(13, 7)
               = (13 \cdot 7):1
               = \overset{10+3}{13} \cdot 7
               = 10 \cdot 7+3 \cdot 7
               = 70+21
               = \boxed{91}
\end{breakaligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I get this error though `LaTeX error: "xparse/unknown-argument-type" Unknown argument type 'b' for the command '\environment breakalign'.` for each environment (I'm using overleaf).

Comment: @soundwave Set up Overleaf to use TeX Live 2018

Comment: This compiles fine on TL2019, but still errors on TL2018.

Comment: @LianTzeLim OK, I added a version for Overleaf.

Comment: @egreg One of a great suggestion...Thanks a lot...It helps me too...

Comment: Thank you for this very nice example. I was trying to readapt it to a problem of mine https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652592/processing-the-body-of-an-ams-alingn-math-environments-to-add-alignment-charact but unfortunately I noticed a deep problem. The `breakaligned` environment does not nest like the aligned one does. In particular if you put a `breakaligned` inside another `breakaligned` then it will not work any more. I think one should add a condition to "stop" at subsequent math environments?

Comment: @GennadyUraltsev Sorry, but you cannot nest. There would be too many cases to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Another (slightly fragile) option is the use [breqn](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/breqn/breqn.pdf), which is the experimental package for automatic line-breaking.

By default, `breqn` will also include linebreaks as `:`, so we need to hide them using `\hiderel{:}`. Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,breqn}
\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}

\begin{document}
\begin{dmath*}
   \lcm(13, 7) = (13 \cdot 7) \hiderel{:}\gcd(13, 7) 
               = (13 \cdot 7)\hiderel{:}1 
               = \overset{10+3}{13} \cdot 7 
               = 10 \cdot 7+3 \cdot 7 
               = 70+21 
               = \boxed{91}
\end{dmath*}
\end{document}
```

[image]