# Processing the body of an ams align math environment (to add alignment characters)

Tags: align, xparse, amsart

I would like to define a variant of the `align*` environment that aligns each column on the left and does not include anything extra in the spacing between columns.

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
Current output with given input:
\begin{align*}
a1&a2&a3=b3=c3&a4\\
b1&b2=a2&b3=c3&b4\\
c1&c2=b2=a2&c3&c4
\end{align*}
Desired output:
\begin{align*}
&a1&&a2&&a3=b3=c3&&a4\\
&b1&&b2=a2&&b3=c3&&b4\\
&c1&&c2=b2=a2&&c3&&c4
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have the result below with the markup above. It can be seen that all one needs to do is

- process every line
- add a '&' character at the beginning of every line
- split every line according to the `&` character into cells
- add a '& &' string at the end of every cell.

Here is my attempt at doing this using `xparse` `\SplitList` and `\ProcessList`. See below for comments

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand { \myalrow } { >{\SplitList{,}} m}
{
  & \ProcessList{#1}{\myalcell} \\
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \myalcell } {m}
{ #1 &&  }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { myale } { >{\SplitList{\\}} b }
{
  \myenv{align*}{\ProcessList{#1}{\myalrow}}
    
}{}

\NewDocumentCommand { \myenv } { mm }
{
  \begin{#1}
  #2
  \end{#1}
}{}


\NewDocumentCommand { \myalc } { >{\SplitList{\\}} m }
{
  \myenv{align*}{\ProcessList{#1}{\myalrow}}
}{}




\begin{document}

\myalc{a1,a2,a3=b3=c3,a4\\
b1,b2=a2,b3=c3,b4\\
c1,c2=b2=a2,c3,c4}

\begin{myale}
a1,a2,a3=b3=c3,a4\\
b1,b2=a2,b3=c3,b4\\
c1,c2=b2=a2,c3,c4
\end{myale}
```

It works both if I define the block as an environment and as a command. Furthermore, according to the AMS technote https://texdoc.org/serve/technote/0 I had to define an auxiliary command `\myenv` that surrounds the output with an environment. If instead of applying `\myenv` I surrounded the output with

```
\begin{align*}
...
\end{align*}
```

nothing works! A huge amount of errors!!!

The only shortcoming of this solution is that I have to separate on the `,`. I would like to spilt on the `&`. However this errors out:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand { \myalrow } { >{\SplitList{&}} m}
{
  & \ProcessList{#1}{\myalcell} \\
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \myalcell } {m}
{ #1 &&  }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { myale } { >{\SplitList{\\}} b }
{
  \myenv{align*}{\ProcessList{#1}{\myalrow}}
    
}{}

\NewDocumentCommand { \myenv } { mm }
{
  \begin{#1}
  #2
  \end{#1}
}{}


\begin{document}
\begin{myale}
1+1=2\\
2+2=4
\end{myale}
\end{document}
```

here are the errors:

```
./aligned-compat2.tex:30: Argument of \token_if_cs:NTF has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.30 \end
         {myale}
Runaway argument?
./aligned-compat2.tex:30: Paragraph ended before \token_if_cs:NTF was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.30 \end
         {myale}
./aligned-compat2.tex:30: Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.30 \end
         {myale}
./aligned-compat2.tex:30: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.30 \end
         {myale}
./aligned-compat2.tex:30: Extra }, or forgotten $.
<recently read> }
                 
l.30 \end
         {myale}
./aligned-compat2.tex:30: Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.30 \end
         {myale}

./aligned-compat2.tex:30: Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;
(amsmath)                trying to recover with `aligned'.
```

and error continue in similar spirit.

Note that the error is there even if there is no symbol `&` in the input.

Furthermore, I tried and `\SplitList` is generally allowed to split on `&`.

What is the missing piece?

Comment: Perhaps `\begin{alignat}{<# of groups>}...\end{alignat}` is what you might be up to. It works exactly like `align` but doesn't add extra spacing. The parameter `<# of groups>` is simply a number of right/left alignment groups, e.g. `A&B  &  C&D` would make 2.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have considered it. Unfortunately, it does not fit my needs. I am really trying to code an altenative to the `array` environment with all alignments specified to be left ones.  This has to be essentially a drop in replacement for the `array` environment so each of the "left aligned" columns is separated by exactly one `&`.  I say "essentially" because it should not require the number of groups to be counted by the user but should do so automatically. I am actually really stumped on any the rewriting does not work that I tried to implement above.

Comment: it only takes a line to modify align to use all left aligment, which is far more efficient than pre-processing the body to double `&&`, and even easier for array. `\newenvironment{abc}{\begin{array}{*{50}{l}}}{\end{array}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are so right!  Somehow did not realize at all that vertical alignment was an option for array environments! When I write math I often have long sequences of equalities. I deal with this by nesting multiple aligned environments but every time I had to add an alignment character. This way I don't need to!

Comment: @GennadyUraltsev don't use `array` for aligned equations it is designed for array/matrices of values, and uses inline textstyle not displaystyle math

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I worked around that using tips from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44407/make-every-element-of-an-array-displaystyle. You are right: `array` is not the right tool for the job. What is then? I would need an `aligned` type environment with single `&` separating the columns and that are left aligned by default. The main advantage of `ams` environments is the correct spacing around `=` but I am not using this: I really just need a nestable multi-row left-aligned environment (even columns are not important, I mostly use one column anyway)